# Error: Call to a member function setStats() on a non-object

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, entity

I am trying to update a single data in my entity class, but the doctrine is always returning this error

```
Error: Call to a member function setStats() on a non-object**
```

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $result = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:UserStats')->findBy(array('ownerPhone' => 1002));

        if( isset($result) && $result !== false ) {
        echo $result->setConditionState(0); // ConditionState is a boolean condition which i want to set it to false

        }
        $em->flush();
```

My **entity** class for conditionState---

```
/**
     * Set conditionState
     *
     * @param boolean $conditionState
     *
     * @return UserStats
     */
    public function setConditionState($conditionState)
    {
        $this->conditionState = $conditionState;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get conditionState
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getConditionState()
    {
        return $this->conditionState;
    }
```

Do anyone have an idea where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Could you post you entity file ?

Comment: Search for all occurences of `->setStats(` in your code.

Comment: Slightly OT, but you can change `if( isset($result) && $result !== false )` to `if (!empty($result))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findBy` method returns an array. Use `findOneBy` instead.